# how to deal with invalid token error in python 3.5 with to_date?

Tags: python, oracle, python-3.x, cx-oracle

I came to know that python 3.x won't accept values like 01, 02 etc,. So, how to deal with this especially while using `To_date()` for SQL queries.

Below is my query

```
cur.execute('select * from COREDEP where PDATE >= To_Date('01-Feb-2016 00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi')')
```

I am getting the below error

```
File "<ipython-input-34-c9e7408a33cb>", line 2
cur.execute('select * from COREDEP where PDATE >= To_Date('01-Feb-2016 00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi')')
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Database- Oracle
Library used - cx_Oracle

Comment: Its a oracle database connected using cx_Oracle library

Comment: "select * from COREDEP where PDATE >= To_Date('01-Feb-2016 00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi')" try to replace ' -> "

Comment: "select * from COREDEP where PDATE >= To_Date('01-Feb-2016 00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi')" try to replace ' -> "

Comment: @LuongDinh Thanks, It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'01-Feb-2016 00:00' is a string, Python shouldn't care what it contains. More importantly it's part of a larger string so Python shouldn't even see it.

I think the problem is the way you've written the SQL statement: you've used the same quote marks for the whole string and the embedded literals. Try using double quotes instead:

```
"select * from COREDEP where PDATE >= To_Date('01-Feb-2016 00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi')"
```

> "what difference does it make with single quote and double quote?"

These quotes are processed by Python:

```
"select * from COREDEP where PDATE >= To_Date('01-Feb-2016 00:00','DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi')"
^                                                                                       ^
```

As far as Pythton is concerned, it's one string.

These quotes are processed by Oracle:

```
"select * from COREDEP where PDATE >= To_Date('01-Feb-2016 00:00','DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi')"
                                               ^                ^  ^                  ^
```

They allow the Oracle database to distinguish the literals in the statement.

> " Ideally both should be same to represent strings, right?"

Up to a point. Look at your original version from the Python compiler's perspective:

```
'select * from COREDEP where PDATE >= To_Date('01-Feb-2016 00:00','DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi')'
^                                             ^
start of string                                end of string
```

Quotes are *paired*. So anything after the matching quote mark is processed by Python as Not A String. That's why Python could see the `01` in the string.

Comment: This worked!!
It would be helpful, if you can explain what difference does it make with single quote and double quote? Ideally both should be same to represent strings, right?